# A PostgreSQL trigger fires on UPDATE not on INSERT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, triggers, full-text-search

I have this `recommendations` table:

```
                                           Table "public.recommendations"
        Column         |            Type             |                          Modifiers                           
-----------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 id                    | integer                     | not null default nextval('recommendations_id_seq'::regclass)
 comment_on_provider   | text                        | 
 created_at            | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at            | timestamp without time zone | not null
 search_vector         | tsvector                    | 
Indexes:
    "recommendations_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "recommendations_search_vector_idx" gin (search_vector)
Triggers:
    recommendations_vector_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON recommendations FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE search_trigger()
```

and this trigger

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
  DECLARE
    search TEXT;
    links_title TEXT;
    links_description TEXT;
  begin
    SELECT string_agg(title, ' ') INTO links_title 
    FROM links
    INNER JOIN recommendations
    ON new.link_id = links.id;

    SELECT string_agg(description, ' ') INTO links_description 
    FROM links
    INNER JOIN recommendations
    ON new.link_id = links.id;

    search := '';
    search := search || ' ' || coalesce(new.comment_on_provider);
    search := search || ' ' || links_title;
    search := search || ' ' || links_description;

    new.search_vector := to_tsvector(search); 
    return new;
  end
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

  CREATE TRIGGER recommendations_vector_update 
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON recommendations
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
    search_trigger();
```

When I insert a record to the `recommendations` table the trigger doesn't fire and `search_vector` is set to null.

But when I update any record it fires and `search_vector` gets updated with the expected values.

**How** to make the trigger working on `INSERT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose in the case of `INSERT` some of the variables in the expressions assigned to the `search` variable are `NULL`. Most probably it's `new.comment_on_provider` but better check.

Comment: An empty string must be passed as a second argument of the call to COALESCE:

search := search || ' ' || COALESCE(new.comment_on_provider, '');

Comment: I will set it as a right answer. some fields are null on `INSERT`. and figured it out to make an `UPDATE` after filling the NULL fields.